# Start MC server on boot into detached screen

Tags: boot, server, ssh, minecraft

So what I'm trying is to start a minecraft server on boot into a detached screen. I would like to be able to reconnect to that screen with ssh to monitor the server. This is what i tried with the "rc.local" file.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

su - bart -c "screen -dmS MC /home/ bart/The\ new\ Server/Start"

exit 0
```

Yet is does not seem to work. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong.

Btw. I'm new to using linux.

Comment: There are already *many* how-to-run-a-minecraft-server-on-Ubuntu tutorials on the internet. Is another really necessary?

Comment: Example: Here's how [I run control and monitor my minecraft server](http://cheesehead-techblog.blogspot.com/2019/08/toggling-minecraft-server-using-systemd.html) using proper systemd tools instead of a terminal multiplexor. To "monitor," I simply read the logfile. More complex to set up (must learn systemd), but super-easy to run.